# How to close the connection properly?

Tags: jdbc, connection

This question has been asked for multiple times and there are a lot of resources talk about this. But it still make me a worry because I think the close() is not working properly.

```
PreparedStatemet pstmt = null;
try {
  pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
  ...
  pstmt.close();
  conn.close();
} catch(...) {
  ...
} finally {
   if(pstmt != null) {
      try {
        pstmt.close();
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        pstmt = null;
      }
   }

   if(conn != null) {
      try {
         conn.close();
       } catch (SQLException e) {
         conn = null;
       }
    }

    System.out.println("PreparedStatement: " + pstmt);
    System.out.println("Connection: " + conn);
}
```

So I expected that it would print out null; but it keep print out the query string and connection path to database.

Comment: Why? It can print out whatever it likes. Your expectation is clearly misplaced.

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand what you mean. I think that when we close the ptsmt and the conn; they both should become null, shoudln't them?

Comment: No. (a) References become null when you set them to null. Not otherwise. (b) What you are seeing is the result of calling toString() on a non-null reference, which can be whatever the class concerned likes.

Answer (score 0):

your code here

```
try {
  PreparedStatemet pstmt = null;
```

creates a pstmt that should not be visible in your finally block, as it is a local variable in another scope.

You probably have another pstmt somewhere outside of your try catch block. which is messing up your check within the finally block.

Try commenting out `PreparedStatemet pstmt = null;` in your try block to see if you code still builds, that will help you identify where exactly do you have the overriding declaration for pstmt.

**EDIT:**
Closing a prepared statement / connection would not mean that the values will be reset. Your connection & prepared statements are indeed closed now, since you are not setting them to null , the data values stored inside are still being printed. That should not be a problem.

Although not a biggie, you can set conn and pstmt to null as well when you closed them that would clear the local memory used by these variables as well. But remember, the connection is still already closed when you do a close call.

Comment: My bad typo, my PreparedStatement is outside of the try-catch block. I edited the code now